# Remote not connecting to Apple TV 4 (2015) model after a factory reset

Tags: appletv, remote-control

Ever since I did a factory reset my remote and Apple TV are not working well together. I'm in the screen where you have to press any button to continue. This doesn't work because it seems like my remote is not connected. No hard feelings, I'll try to connect it. I have to press the MENU and volume UP button for about 5 seconds.

When I do this, the Apple TV does recognise me trying to pair the remote, as it says that I need to bring the remote closer to the Apple TV to continue the pairing. When I do this however it seems like the pairing is not being done and it seems to freeze. At the very top a message appears where it asks me to press the MENU and volume UP button together again.

It doesn't matter what I try but unfortunately it does not pair and it does not let me past the setup screen. Is it possible to do this setup without my remote, for example using my Macbook Pro?